# Oracle ADF ADF_FACES-30188 Error: Illegal inlineStyle Definition in panelGridLayout - How to Resolve?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Looking for expertise on resolving an ADF_FACES-30188 error in WebLogic
`<Error> <oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.grid.CellGatherCallback> <ADF_FACES-30188> <Illegal inlineStyle definition detected in panelGridLayout clientId="pt1:pt_pgl1", gridRow id="pt_gr4", gridCell id="pt_gc4", inlineStyle="height:30px;". Only non-geometric styles can be safely used, e.g. background-color.>`

In Oracle Support, I searched for a solution but couldn't find any results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.